# NumberFomatException error in Java when inputting first line of file

Tags: java, syntax-error, number-formatting

I am attempting to input a file of weights for a local Java Challenge considering whether the sum of the weights in each row is under the 5-pound weight limit. It is yielding a `NumberFormatException`. Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("postofficedat.txt"));

    int lines = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
      double sum = .4;

      for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
        sum = sum + input.nextDouble();
      }

      if (sum < 5) {
        System.out.println("OK");
      } else {
        System.out.println("OVERWEIGHT");
      }

      if (i < lines - 1) {
        input.nextLine();
      }
    }
    input.close();
  }
}
```

This is the input file with the first being the number of lines and the following lines being the weights:

```
3
1.21 0.33 1.42 0.90 0.45 1.30 0.30
1.20 0.59 1.23 0.99 0.05 0.10 0.07
0.62 0.61 0.63 0.64 0.65 0.66 2.67
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

Comment: Your stacktrace contains "java.base" before the java.lang. What's that? I have not seen it. Secondly, try to delete the first line from the file, and then manually write 3 and hit enter - this will make sure that the 3 what we humans see is ALSO 3 from the computer's understanding too. Sometimes there could be hidden character or whatever something that prevents program to work properly but we humans see it perfectly fine.

Comment: @Ketan The modulerisation done in Java 9 means that all the Java Runtime Library classes belong to a named module. `java.base` is the module name of all the core Java classes.

Comment: Parsing fails because your file starts with a BOM, which is an invisible character added by some text editors when writing UTF-8 or UTF-16 encoded files. Tell your text editor to not write a BOM. E.g. NotePad++ has that option, so you can open the file in NotePad++ and save it back without the BOM.

Comment: @Ketan This worked, thank you!

Comment: @Mia if you want more info on what Andreas said about this BOM, check this good link https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-tale-about-feff-the-invisible-character-cd25cd4630e7/

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to get an Integer with the `Scanner`. `Scanner` provides a couple of convenient methods that let you read in various types.

`.nextLine()` will attempt to read in the next line as a String which requires a type conversion if you want to handle it as an `int`

You can use the method `.nextInt()` to pull in the next integer.